# gvim syntax highlight for different types of lines

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, file-format, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've done several syntax highlighting files for simple custom formats in the past (even changing the format a bit to be capable of making the syntax file basing on my *skills*, in effects).

But this time I feel confused and I will appreciate some help.

The file format is (obviously) a text file where every line contain three distinct elements separated by spaces, they can be "symbols" (names containing a series of alphanumerical chars plus hyphens) or "string" (a series of any chars, spaces included, but not pipes).

Strings can be only at start or end of a line, the middle element can be only a symbol. And string are delimited by a pipe at the end if it is the first element and at the start if it is the last element.

But a line can be also all symbols, string first and rest symbols, and string last and rest symbols.

Strings are always followed by a pipe if they are the first element, or
with a pipe as prefix if they are the last element.

Examples:

All symbols

```
this-is-a-symbol another-one and-another
```

First string

```
This is a string potentially containing any char| symbol symbol
```

Last string

```
symbol symbol |A string at the end of the line
```

First and last as strings

```
This is a string| now-we-have-a-symbol |And here another string
```

This four examples are the only possibilities available for a correct formatting.

All symbols need to be colored differently, a specific color for first element, a specific color for second, and one for third.
But strings will have one unique different color regardless of position.

If the pipe chars can be "dimmed" with a color similar (not precisely the same) to background this will be a big plus. But I think I can manage this myself.

A line in the file not like the ones showed will have to be highlighted as an error (like red background).

Some help?

ps: stackoverflow apply a sort of syntax highlighting to my examples which can be misleading

Comment: That's a crazy format. (It's also ambiguous.)

Comment: I think it is practical and concise for the purpose it needs to serve, it is well defined and I can parse it quite easily and unanbiguosly with regexp. But I don't know how to syntax highlight it in Vim, in this context I agree it is crazy, because I can not even start to do it...

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simpler approach than what I initially thought was necessary in terms of regular expressions. At end I just need to match the first element and the last, how can I've not think of that... So this is my solution, it seems to work well for my specifics. It only doesn't highlight bad formatted lines. Good enough for now. Thanks for the patience and the attention.

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language:         ff .txt

if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

setlocal iskeyword+=:

syn match Asymbol /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]* /
syn match Csymbol / [a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$/
syn match Astring /^.*| /
syn match Cstring / |.*$/

highlight link Asymbol Constant
highlight link Csymbol Statement
highlight link Astring Include
highlight link Cstring Comment

let b:current_syntax = "ff"
```